# Jamine test case fails only in jenkins job with Error: asynchronous test timed out

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm facing a weird issue, jasmine test cases are successful on my local machine and it fails only in the jenkins job with the below error,

Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out

I have few asynchronous unit tests (with setTimeouts and callbacks). I always make sure the done() has been called after all the assertion has been made.

I don't have any issues on my local machine, only in jenkins.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a caching issue on the Jenkins job. After clearing the cached data in the workspace before the job it works fine.